# bash: translate a string to replace combination of 'character+whitespace' with comma

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to translate(tr) a string to replace combination of two characters with comma.

string:-
input is `"test-1 - test-2 - test-3"`
desired output is `"test-1 ,test-2 ,test-3"`

To achieve this I need to replace " -" [space + '-'] with comma [,]

I tried the below options

```
$ echo "test-1 - test-2 - test-3" | tr '-[:space:]' ','
$ echo "test-1 - test-2 - test-3" | tr '- ' ','
```

but throwing an error?, it works for a combination of any other two charachters but not with space?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` instead of `tr` to achieve this:

```
$ echo "test-1 - test-2 - test-3" | sed "s/ - / ,/g"
```